# Bash config file or command line parameters

Tags: linux, bash, parameters

If I am writing a bash script, and I choose to use a config file for parameters. Can I still pass in parameters for it via the command line?  I guess I'm asking can I do both on the same command?

The watered down code:

```
#!/bin/bash 

source builder.conf 
function xmitBuildFile { 
    for IP in "{SERVER_LIST[@]}" 
    do 
        echo $1@$IP 
    done 
} 
xmitBuildFile
```

builder.conf:

```
SERVER_LIST=( 192.168.2.119 10.20.205.67 )
```

---

`$bash> ./builder.sh myname`

My expected output should be `myname@192.168.2.119` and `myname@10.20.205.67`, but when I do an `$ echo $#`, I am getting 0, even when I passed in 'myname' on the command line.

Comment: I'm calling you out on not having googled this first.  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-parameters/index.html

Comment: almost certainly, but without code or defining "config file", this question cannot be answered

Comment: I'm not exactly going to get nasty, however, I DID google it first, and in the search that it returned, it didn't return anything except how to's and nothing to do with having both in the script.  So my advice, don't try to get rep points for calling someone out on something if you don't have all of the information.  :: cheers ::

Comment: you shebang is wrong, should be #!/bin/bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the "config file" is just a piece of shell sourced into the main script (usually containing definitions of some variables), like this:

```sh
. /etc/script.conf
```

of course you can use the positional parameters anywhere (before or after ". /etc/..."):

```sh
echo "$@"
test -n "$1" && ...
```

you can even define them in the script or in the very same config file:

```sh
test $# = 0 && set -- a b c
```

Comment: You missed passing of the parameters down to your function:
`xmitBuildFile "$@"` or only the first `xmitBuildFile "$1"`

Comment: This is because the functions have their own set of positional parameters (aka arguments)

Comment: Ah I understand now, thank you for clearing that one up.  It works :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Furthemore, it depends on your architecture of script. You can overwrite parametrs with values from config and vice versa.

By the way [shflags](http://code.google.com/p/shflags/) may be pretty useful in writing such script.